# Are Couchbase multi-node cluster a single point of failure when using PHP Client Library?

Tags: php, couchbase

In the Couchbase [PHP Client Library Documentation](http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-sdk-php-1.1/accessing-php.html) you can read:

> If you are running a multi-node cluster, you only need to point to a
>   single node in a cluster as the PHP extension will transparently
>   determine any cluster topology and route requests to the right servers
>   as well as react on topolgy changes.

My question is, what if the node your application is pointing to is down when you instantiate the couchbase class? It isn't a single point of failure? What can I do to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can pass list of known endpoints of the cluster to constructor as array

```
    $hosts = array('example.com', 'example.org:8091');
    $cb = new Couchbase($hosts, $user, $passwd, $bucket);
```